# Custom combination disables the native function of a key

Tags: autohotkey

I don't have the <kbd>Right WIN</kbd>  key on my keyboard :

[image]

So I can't lock the computer with my right hand with <kbd>right WIN</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

So I created this script :

```
#NoTrayIcon
AppsKey & L:: DllCall("LockWorkStation")
Return
```

Which locks the station via : <kbd>Appskey</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> instead.
It does work and the station is being locked.
But I've found out that the <kbd>Appskey</kbd> (alone)  doesn't work anymore.

**Question**

What is wrong with my script and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line anywhere (it must be on its own line) in the code:

```
AppsKey::AppsKey
```

This happens because when defining custom combinations, the first *key* becomes the *prefix key* and loses its original function. In your example the *prefix key* was `AppsKey`.

Comment: BTW , I think my title is not SEO friendly regarding people who will have the same problem. If you think that there's a better title for this question  - please fill free to edit. I mean my first intuitive search would be  : context menu key , without hooked keyword. well... you get my point.